# brushless alternator with external regulator

Tags: alternator

I'm interested in using a Delco Remy 38si with an external voltage regulator.  Obviously, the voltage regulators can be removed on these units, but I'd like to know whether anyone has modified one (or any of the other Delco Remy brushless alternators) to pull the field out to an external terminal.

I know this modification is pretty easy on a brushed alternator, and it seems like it'd be about as easy on a brushless alt, despite the differences.  Am I missing something?

Has anyone done this on a DR brushless alt?

Thanks in advance for any response!

Peter

Edit:

Sorry if this doesn't seem to be about motor vehicle maintenance or repair. I am asking about alternators usually used in motor vehicles (specifically, busses and long haul trucks).

Reason I'm asking is that I'm looking for a less expensive expensive alternative for an alternator intended for marine use to charge a large battery bank with a very high charge acceptance rate.

The Delco 38SI and 40SI have the current output I'm looking for in a package that can handle extended output at high current.

The application requires multistep regulation, however, which the internal regulator doesn't do. If I can pull the alternator field out to a terminal though, external regulators are readily available to maintain the multistep charge profile I need.

I've seen a few comments about modifying internally regulated alternators for older vehicles that were originally equipped with external regulators, to use current parts and maintain a stock installation. Those are brushed alternators though.

Was hoping someone here might know something about this… Thanks for the input!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Out of curiosity, is there any real reason why you'd want to?

Comment: I don't know about brushless alts but brushless motors usually run off of an ac current. It is possible to remove the regulator but I'm not sure if you'd get the AC current or an unregulated rectified ac (DC). Also as Paulster2 said, why?

Comment: Cross posted with comments here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/496799/152903

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about motor vehicle maintenance or repair.